# Power Automate calling Azure Function returning "BadRequest" even though the function returns "Ok"

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, power-automate

I'm finding this one baffling.

I have an Azure Function which I am calling from a Power Automate "Flow" using the HTTP connector.

The function is simple - you post a small JSON content containing some binary file data (as a Base64 encoded string) and it returns the document contents in plain text.

I'm using the "key / code" approach in the header (not OAuth).

If I construct a "basic" text payload in the body of my request then I get the expected error message back from my Function (that it was an invalid Base 64 Encoded string). This confirms;

- It is successfully executing my query and authenticating
- My code is executing as expected, and the correct (custom) error message is being returned

However!! When I try to send an *actual* Base64 encoded string then the Flow tells me that the Request failed:

*BadRequest : The content is not a valid JSON*

HOWEVER (and this is the really confusing bit) when I check the logs of the Azure Function it shows that all of the logic is executing correctly and a 200 OK response was returned.

I have automated unit tests in C# so I **know** that the function is correctly returning the correct status code and content in the response body.

A final snippet here:

If I remove the "==" from the end of the Base64 string then the "not a valid JSON" error goes away, and I'm back to my custom code error again (the string is not a valid Base64 encoded value)

Help!!
Is this some weird encoding issue with Power Automate?

Update: screenshots

[image: Flow HTTP request]

[image: Response "BadRequest"]

For reference - if I post a "non-Base64" encoded string to the same endpoint, I get a full OUTPUTS response - this is actually the custom error message I would expect to see coming from my Azure Function - and you can see the Status Code, Headers and Body (containing my own custom error message)

[image: Response 400 when using non-base64 value in the body]

Comment: Did you tried by passing `Content-Type: application/json` in a request headers while calling the function url? It's optional but recommended as a good practice.

Comment: Yes, I have that header value. I'll post some screenshots of the whole thing once I get back to my computer (on my phone right now)